# Getting user's work and education fields using Facebook API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I managed to get the Education and Work fields for my profile, but I was wondering if it's possible to get it for a specific user? If so, what would be the Graph API statement for it?

This is how I managed to do it in Android Studio;

```
private Request newRequest(Session session) {
        Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "/me", null);

        Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
        String[] requestFields = new String[]{"work, education"};
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requestFields));

        Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
        parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
        request.setParameters(parameters);

        return request;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `/me` with the respective User Access Token. Without that, you cannot receive the User-specific information anyway.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens

Comment: Sure, but when I want to access my profile, works without it :) basically I want to access somebody else's work and education details, there probably in that case I have to use the access token. But then how will the query look like?

Comment: Like I said, `/me`. The respective user_id is determined by the used User Access Token (it's encoded within). And, by the way, it's all in the docs!

Comment: Haha, cheers, mate! It's that I've been querying FB for so many things and the syntax is just incredibly different, therefore I find it complicated to understand its logic sometimes :)

Comment: I'm retrieving some user info already without the access token, such as common FB friends, likes

Comment: You surely cannot acces a User likes without an Access Token

Comment: The only thing I pass in is his Facebook ID and that does the trick

EDIT : It's only the Facebook ID, not the access token :) And that solved my problem as well. A big of a misunderstanding

Comment: `/me` always works in conjunction with an User Access Token. Not sure what you're doing...

Answer (score 1):

Passing the user's FB ID and the field I want to access, how could this be wrong if it returns what I'm looking for?

```
 private Request newRequest(Session session) {
        Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, profile.getFacebook_id(), null);

        Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
        String[] requestFields = new String[]{"work, education"};
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requestFields));

        Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
        parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
        request.setParameters(parameters);

        return request;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for this, unfortunately, Facebook no longer returns this data. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/user

[image: Facebook API reference]

[image: Facebook API reference]